# Is there a way in Apache Tika we can Identify chart data inside a docx file

Tags: apache-poi, apache-tika

I have a docx file with text, images, tables, and charts. I want to process everything except charts. But I could not get any additional media type or content type that tells me this content is a chart. I was able to get information about images.

Is there a way in the apache tika 2.8 version, which detects charts data and then I can ignore it and process everything else?

I have used Apache POI as well and we can easily get the chart data, but since my code base is using Apache tika, I would like to stick to it. But in case of no answers, would love to explore Apache POI as well.

I have used the below code without any luck.

```
    @Test
public void testMaxEmbedded() throws Exception {
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    Parser p = new AutoDetectParser();
    RecursiveParserWrapper wrapper = new RecursiveParserWrapper(p, true);
    ContentHandlerFactory contentHandlerFactory =
            new BasicContentHandlerFactory(BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.BODY, -1);

    RecursiveParserWrapperHandler handler =
            new RecursiveParserWrapperHandler(contentHandlerFactory, -1);
    InputStream bufferedIn = new FileInputStream(WORD_MANUSCRIPT);
    InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(bufferedIn);

    try (stream) {
        wrapper.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
    }
    List<Metadata> metadataList = handler.getMetadataList();
}
```